# URL Segments Keep Building Up (Using Navee)

Tags: url, segments, navee

URL segments keep building up with each link I click -- Never had this issue occur before.

Navee include:

{exp:navee:nav nav_title="main"}
[image]

The first time I click the link, it works fine: 
[image]

When I click another link, it adds the previous link to the new click link:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start your URLs with a forward slash so:

`work/category/web/`

becomes

`/work/category/web/`